# org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not update JavaObjectHere

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, web-services, soap

Hi Im using Hibernate and Spring for my WebService project. When Im sending a SOAP request through SOAPUI, I couldn't update the object in the database because hibernate is giving off this kind of error:

```
 JDBC exception on Hibernate data access; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not update: [org.game.model.HeroChampion#123456]
```

this HeroChampion is a part of a `many-to-one` relationship inside another object, let's say SkillObject.

Anyone who used Hibernate before can surely relate to this problem.

Which part should I start checking? the dao.savemethod? or the relationship between the two tables?

If you need more info , ask away. Thanks.
BTW, this is webservice is a 2 part project. The main webservice interpreting soap requests and the client project making the soap requests. Right now Im working on the client project.

Additional ERROR that might help:

```
SEVERE: Could not synchronize database state with session
```

one of the save methods is:

```
 public void saveHeroChampion(final HeroCHampion heroObj) { 
        getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(heroObj); 
        getHibernateTemplate().flush();
 }
```

Do you think I should add (or is this trivial? )

```
getHibernateTemplate().refresh(heroObj);
```

Currently the Cascade type of the Parent is set to NONE, do I change it to Cascade = MERGE?

```
 /** 
     * 
     * @hibernate.set inverse="true" cascade="merge" order-by="SST_TEST_SERIES ASC"
     * @hibernate.collection-key column="SST_HERO_ID_FK"
     * @hibernate.collection-one-to-many class="org.game.model.HeroSkills"  lazy="false"
     * @struts.form-field
     */
```

Comment: It will be a lot easier to get help if you show some code, the entities and the save method are a good start.

Comment: @MarcosBarbero hey man, thanks for droppying by. I see you're a SA and Java dev. Have you encountered this before? this is pretty common with objects with  many-to-one relationships . Which part do you start checking ?

Comment: So, if you could share your mapped classes and the save methods that would be helpful for everyone

Comment: @MarcosBarbero thanks, can you check my updated question if the savemethod helps a bit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SEVERE: Could not synchronize database state with session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60635336/severe-could-not-synchronize-database-state-with-session)

Comment: @rakwaht It didnt. Do I have to set the many-to-one entity to Cascade.MERGE? or Cascade.ALL?