# SEVERE: Could not synchronize database state with session

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, web-services, soap

When trying to update an Entity in Hibernate Im getting this ERROR:

```
SEVERE: Could not synchronize database state with session
```

So the request is not being saved to database.
My entity has many-to-one relationship.

What should I do?

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateJdbcException: JDBC exception on Hibernate data access; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not update: [org.game.model.HeroChampion#1234567]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:634)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:695)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:566)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:540)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:510)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:310)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:117)

JDBC exception on Hibernate data access; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not update:
```

Do I need to perform a session.refresh as stated in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18561114/6143482)?